# In querydsl, how is a subquery performed in the FROM clause?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, querydsl

I have this query:

```
select gf_storage_zone_type,
       sum(numObjectPhysicalName) numObjects
from (
         select gf_storage_zone_type,
                count(distinct gf_object_physical_name) as numObjectPhysicalName
         from t_kgov_kpi_streaming_object
         group by gf_storage_zone_type,
                  gf_object_physical_name
         order by gf_storage_zone_type
     ) as v
group by gf_storage_zone_type
```

I am trying to use QueryDSL in Java with Spring, where one of my methods contains:

```
NumberPath<Long> numObjectPhysicalName = Expressions.numberPath(Long.class, "numObjectPhysicalName");
NumberPath<Long> numObjects = Expressions.numberPath(Long.class, "numObjects");
QKpiRuleBoard qKpiRuleBoard = QKpiRuleBoard.kpiRuleBoard;
List<ObjectsByStorageZoneProjection> objectsByStorageZone = jpaQueryFactory
                .select(Projections.constructor(ObjectsByStorageZoneProjection.class,
                        qKpiRuleBoard.storageZoneType,
                        numObjectPhysicalName.sum().as(numObjects)))
                .from(JPAExpressions
                        .select(
                                Projections.constructor(ObjectsByStorageZoneProjection.class,
                                qKpiRuleBoard.storageZoneType,
                                qKpiRuleBoard.objectPhysicalName.countDistinct().count().as(numObjectPhysicalName)))
                        .from(qKpiRuleBoard)
                        .where(
                                qKpiRuleBoard.cutoffDate.eq(cutoffDate)
                                        .and(qKpiRuleBoard.countryId.eq(countryId))
                                        .and(qKpiRuleBoard.executionFrequencyType.eq(executionFrequencyType)))
                        .groupBy(
                                qKpiRuleBoard.storageZoneType,
                                qKpiRuleBoard.objectPhysicalName))
                .groupBy(qKpiRuleBoard.storageZoneType)
                .fetch();
```

Throwing the following exception -> com.querydsl.jpa.impl.JPAQuery cannot be cast to com.querydsl.core.types.EntityPath

What can I do to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Usually your query will create an *[inline view](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/views-in-sql#types-of-views)* given a subquery is being used in the `from` clause.

QueryDSL works with JPA behind the scene, and for now, they do not support subqueries in the `from` clause based on the [docs](https://openjpa.apache.org/builds/3.1.2/apache-openjpa/docs/jpa_langref.html#jpa_langref_subqueries).

> Support for subqueries in the FROM clause will be considered in a later release of the specification.

You will have to rewrite your query to adapt it to JPA or use native query.

I believe you will achieve the same result using the query below.

```
select
    gf_storage_zone_type,
    count(distinct gf_object_physical_name) as numObjects
from
    t_kgov_kpi_streaming_object
group by
    gf_storage_zone_type
order by
    gf_storage_zone_type;
```

This can easily be translated to JPA.